# Get filenames in a given directory jQuery

Tags: jquery, directory, directory-listing

I'd like to get a list of filenames that will later be stored into an array. The following code just displays directory listing in the same way Apache  listing is displayed in a browser, e. g. `1234.txt 31-Aug-2016 13:17 35K` How to change it, so I get just the filenames?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.get("dat/", function(data) {
    $("#files").append(data);
  });
});
</script>
<body>
<div id='files'></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try with below code. openFile function is useful to check whether it is file or folder. Please add more extensions in function as per your use.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var fileNames = new Array();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/test/",
      success: function(data){
         $(data).find("td > a").each(function(){
            if(openFile($(this).attr("href"))){
                fileNames.push($(this).attr("href"));
            }           
         });
      }
    }); 
    console.log(fileNames);
    function openFile(file) {
        var extension = file.substr( (file.lastIndexOf('.') +1) );
        switch(extension) {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'png':
            case 'gif':   // the alert ended with pdf instead of gif.
            case 'zip':
            case 'rar':
            case 'pdf':
            case 'php':
            case 'doc':
            case 'docx':
            case 'xls':
            case 'xlsx':
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: nicely done.no need of that break , return will work, we need to parse the html before implementing the logic.

Comment: I tried this and got a 403 forbidden error

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem. I needed to load all the file names from a specified directory. so I made a function

```
function loadFileNames(dir) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            var fileNames = new Array();
            $.ajax({
                url: dir,
                success: function (data) {
                    for(var i = 1; i < $(data).find('li span.name').length; i++){
                        var elem = $(data).find('li span.name')[i];
                        fileNames.push(elem.innerHTML);
                    }
                    return resolve(fileNames);
                }
            });
        } catch (ex) {
            return reject(new Error(ex));
        }
    });
}
```

then you call this function like this

```
loadFileNames('/resource/seed/files')
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert('Files could not be loaded. please check console for details');
            console.error(error);
        });
```

Comment: I tried this and got a 403 forbidden error